# Scringo Facebook , app id logcat issues , Facebook login works with Parse SDK not with Scringo

Tags: android, facebook, scringo

I use parse sdk and scringo in my app , parse works fine for my login with facebook so app_id is set correctly , but when login via scringo it just shows please wait

any help !!

Logcat

Scringo(11060): You need to set the facebook app id in the manifest. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/upgrading-from-2.0-to-3.0/#login

how to go ahead with facebook sdk and scringo , the site is not informative and even the api docs dont explain much , no reply over email so i have to turn to SO for help

EDIT:

I use broadcast receiver now as per their guides , how to login correctly 
http://www.scringo.com/docs/android-guides/popular/handling-login-status-changes/

Comment: To who ever marked my question as -1 thanks for the help , struggling as it to get some reputation and with the code , great site !!

Comment: Its time to upload your manifest, relevant part of strings.xml and the relevant block of code I think

Comment: Got a reply from scringo team , testing my theory and the solution they suggested will update as soon i have some leads for the complete solution , thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is a problem common to all Facebook libraries,  you need to create an application on Facebook and get an id/key (http://www.scringo.com/docs/android-guides/popular/connect-to-social-networks/), most libraries then require that you set it in the manifest. I haven't used this library, if you want to try using https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook I can provide more help (if you need it, Simple Facebooks guide is pretty good), otherwise this hopefully makes it clear what you're missing

According to their quick start guide, Scringo it turns out also has it's own App Ids which you get through a dashboard, take a look here: http://www.scringo.com/docs/android-guides/quickstart/

Comment: Well , i am way past that , have my app running with configured Facebook app and its app id in my manifest , i used Parse (part of facebook) , now the trouble comes with scringo sdk and logins , no help anywhere not even support from them so !!, let me know if i am not clear enough with my problem and thanks for the reply

Comment: Your log cat is giving a pretty definitive issue, check the scringo docs again, you might find that scringo checks a different meta tag than the official facebook sdk does (Im just guessing here)

Comment: I just looked at the scringo docs, they do indeed check another app id, see the link in my answer edit

Comment: hey i have done extensive through search of their api ,all they say is call Scringo.loginwithFacebook(activity calling ); and beyond it just a broadcast reciever to register with , which i have done , but my app now logins with facebook and shows me a please wait screen , if i back press i get back to my activity where i called login from facebook . hope some scringo users or devs here can help!!

Comment: the app id is their SDK id , I'm getting appid errors for facebook (cant be possible as i am successfully login in and out via other calls made via non Scringo sdk methods)

Comment: I would add "my app now logins with facebook" to your question to make it clearer (that changes the context somewhat) - anyone else who views your issue isnt likely to read these comments.

Comment: Have you added @string/replace_this_facebook_app_id  to the xml resources?

Comment: YES to both the scringo sdk that i reference to and also my own project , if it where wrong facebook app id then my app feature where i use Facebook graph would fail

Comment: No, because you said that when you were successful it was "via other calls made via non Scringo sdk" and the standard Facebook SDK does NOT use that string

Comment: I have made sure my app runs with facebook features (lets say i dont have Scringo now anywhere) , its just that when i call login with facebook from Scringo SDK it logins in but does not respond or rather is not saved for Scringo internals (userID or other features of Scringo SDK)

Comment: Sorry, I'd like to help but I don't know any more about scringo, it's possible that you have to implement/supply a callback yourself though which Scringo will notify when complete and that it's then your job to proceed from there, that's quite common with asynchronous libraries

Comment: Thanks a ton , but yes i am unclear of such possible ways or callbacks , as its not clearly mentioned on their site anywhere , trying my best to see and work it out , one offtopic qn , how can i get some user on this site to answer by mentioning him ??

Comment: thanks i shall wait for an answer or hopefully solve my own :D , thanks for ur patience

Comment: I hope you managed to fix your problem. If this has pointed you in the right direction please mark it as the accepted answer now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.

I fixed it by adding my `scringo app id` in the `scringo.properties` file under the assets folder of my project:

`scringo.app.id="your_scringo_app_id"`

Hope it helps.